# push update to next js in production

Tags: next.js

I deployed my next js app using AWS EC2. if i want to push some code change to production, should i run `next build` again? i run `npm run start` but nextjs doesn't run my updated code base. based on [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/Deployment), we only need run `next build` once in production. btw i'm using [custom server and routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/#custom-server-and-routing).

if i run `next build` it get so slow to rebuild the app. anyone know how to speed it up? Thanks

edit:

here is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "something",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"
  },
  "author": "Handmadenesia",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.388.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
 },
 "babel": {
   "env": {
     "development": {
     "presets": [
        "next/babel"
     ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "styled-components",
        {
          "ssr": true,
          "displayName": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "production": {
    "presets": [
      "next/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "styled-components",
        {
          "ssr": true,
          "displayName": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave is specifically talking about running multiple instances of the same build, it even explains why this is the case (it's because you want to have the same `BUILD_ID` so each instance is identical).

If you've made changes to your app, yes, you need to build it again with `next build`.

Without seeing your app, I don't think anyone can tell you why your build is slow.

Comment: oh good to know. i've updated my question with my package.json file. thanks